# getting an neutral element for std::multiply and std::plus

Tags: c++, stl, template-meta-programming

While implementing a template class whose constructor takes:

1. vector of functions (functions are of type `std::function<bool(const T&)>`)
2. `std::binary_function<bool,bool,bool>` that I will use to accumulate results of applications of vector from 1) to certain value.

I want to be able to use `std::plus()` and `std::multiplies()` as second template parameter, but the problem is that depending on the function I need a corresponding neutral element (for std accumulate init value). For `AND` (`std::multiplies`) I need `true` (aka `1`), for `OR` (`std::plus`) I need `false` (aka `0`). I know I could just specialize the template and problem solved but I wonder if there is a way to get neutral element for a built in STL function.

Comment: FWIW in mathematics the "neutral element" is called an "identity element", or just "the identity". Hence `0` is the "additive identity" and `1` is the "multiplicative identity" in the field modulo 2.

Comment: You want some kind of universal neutral element, independent on AND or OR, that locally specializes? can you provide an example of use?

Comment: @SteveJessop sorry in my country(when talking about Group Theory) we call it something that literally translates to neutral element in English. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Acorbe like the example says I want to "multiply accumulate"  or "plus accumulate", where multiply or plus are template params, so I need a mapping from plus to 0, and from multiply to 1.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: No problem, I wasn't confused. I thought that knowing the term might help you search, and/or give names to the code you write :-) Now that I know it's a translation issue, the latter is irrelevant if you don't name your code entities in English of course.

Comment: btw one weird question... will std::plus and std::multiplies behave on bools like I guestimate that they do(aka as logical OR and logicak AND)

Comment: In one of Stepanov books, I think I saw the code passing the identity element as an extra parameter in the function calls `template<class Operator, class T> void function(Operator op, T x, T y, T op_identity){...}`. Which can be a workaround sometimes (since the caller might know what is the Operator type).

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `gcc`, you can use [__gnu_cxx::identity_element](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.2/group__SGIextensions.html#g91e15bd7fbf8923cebc1a08b8cdba724), which is doing exactly what you're asking for.

If you're not, I don't think there is a general solution, as if there was, `gcc` wouldn't have implemented their own - you might just rewrite their implementation (which is actually just a couple of template specializations, as you expected).

Edit: the source code for this is on lines 78-98 of [this file](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/libstdc++-html-USERS-4.2/ext_2functional-source.html).

Comment: Im not using gcc, Im on VC10, but nice info. :D

Comment: Also, in STLab, https://stlab.adobe.com/structadobe_1_1identity__element_3_01std_1_1multiplies_3_01T_01_4_01_4.html

Answer (score 4):

The usual solution here is traits.  Rather than instantiate your
template on `std::plus` or whatever, you would instantiate it on a
traits class, which defines a `typedef` for `std::plus`, plus an 
identity element (static const, with initializer), and anything else you
need.  Something like:

```
struct OpTraitsAdd
{
    typedef std::plus<int> Op;
    static int const identity = 0;
};

struct OpTraitsMult
{
    typedef std::multiplies<int> Op;
    static int const identity = 1;
};
```

It's also possible to obtain the traits from the standard operator,
using explicit specialization:

```
template <typename Op> struct OpTraits;
template<>
struct OpTraits<std::plus<int> >
{
    static int const identity = 0;
};
template<>
struct OpTraits<std::multiplies<int> >
{
    static int const identity = 1;
};
```

In this case, you would instantiate your class over the operator, and
use `OpTraits<Op>::identity` when needed.

In both cases, of course, you do have to provide all of the necessary
traits, either as independent classes or as template specializations.
If the only two identity elements you need are 0 and 1, you might be
able to do it automatically with something like:

```
template <bool idIs0> struct IdImpl;
template<>
struct IdImpl<false>
{
    static int value = 1;
};
template<>
struct IdImpl<true>
{
    static int value = 0;
};

template <typename Op>
struct Id
{
    static int value = ItImpl<Op(1, 0) == 1>::value;
};
```

This will *not* work pre-C++11, since `Op(1, 0)` is not a constant
epxression.  I'm not sure about C++11; but I think that if
`Op::operator()` is declared `constexpr`, it should work.  (I'd only
bother trying if I had to cover a lot of operators, including some that
clients might provide.)

Comment: Another way to express that clever part at the end is that assuming `Op` has an identity at all, then in `bool` the identity is `!(Op(true,false))`. Because if `a*b == a` then `b` is the identity, and if `a*b == b` then `a` is the identity. This does rely on `Op` satisfying the requirements for a group operation, though. If the user supplies an Op that maps any inputs to `0`, then it doesn't have an identity and so auto-detection will guess wrong and continue, while the traits approach presumably would fail to compile since there wouldn't be a suitable specialization for `Op`.

Comment: And armed with that information, you could just compute the identity at run-time in C++03.

Answer (score 3):

Just to pick out one point from James's answer (and my comment to it). I think it deserves to be considered separately.

If you want to you can compute the identity at runtime, assuming that there really is an identity. It's `!func(true, false)`.

If `func::operator()` is available and free of side-effects, as it is for `std::plus` and `std::multiplies`, then presumably any sensible compiler will actually compute that at compile time. But it doesn't need the value at compile time, so now your template could (if the caller wants) accept a `std::function<bool(bool,bool)>` instead of needing to know the actual accumulate operation at compile-time.